# Match Where Multiple Columns are... PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have a search query which works, but not the way I had hope. Here:

```
 try{
    /*

    Create Search Query. 

    */

    //Include database config file.
    include('config.php');
    //Get values from Angular.
    $valuesPost=$_POST;
    $values=array();
    foreach ($valuesPost as $rows) {
        $decodedValues=json_decode($rows, TRUE);
        $values[]=$decodedValues;
    }
    //Get table from post values.
    $table=$values[0]["table"];
    //Get limit from post values.
    $limit=$values[0]["limit"];
    //Get offset from post values.
    $offset=$values[0]["offset"];
    //Get orderBy from post values.
    $orderBy=$values[0]["orderBy"];
    //Unset Whole array
    unset($values[0]);

    //Create cats fields
        $cats=array_keys($values[1]);
        if(empty($cats)) {
            $cats = null;
        } else {
            foreach($cats as &$val){
                $val="cat_id = :".$val;
            }
            $cats=implode(" OR ", $cats);
        }
    //Create subCats fields
        $subCats=array_keys($values[2]);
        if(empty($values[2])) {
            $subCats[0] = null;
        } else {
            foreach($subCats as &$val){
                $val="sub_cat_id = :".$val;
            }
            $subCats=implode(" OR ", $subCats);
        }
    //Create colourCats fields
        $colourCats=array_keys($values[3]);
        if(empty($colourCats)) {
            $colourCats[0] = null;
        } else {
            foreach($colourCats as &$val){
                $val="colour_id = :".$val;
            }
            $colourCats=implode(" OR ", $colourCats);
        }
    $where = "";
    //Create Where Statement
        if(empty($cats[0]) && empty($subCats[0])){
            $where = $colourCats;
        }
        if(empty($cats[0]) && empty($colourCats[0])){
            $where = $subCats;
        }
        if(empty($subCats[0]) && empty($colourCats[0])){
            $where = $cats;
        }
        if(empty($colourCats[0]) && !empty($cats[0]) && !empty($subCats[0])){
            $where = $cats." AND ".$subCats;
        }
        if(empty($subCats[0]) && !empty($cats[0]) && !empty($colourCats[0])){
            $where = $cats." AND ".$colourCats;
        }
        if(empty($cats[0]) && !empty($subCats[0]) && !empty($colourCats[0])){
            $where = $subCats." AND ".$colourCats;
        }
        if(!empty($cats[0]) && !empty($subCats[0]) && !empty($colourCats[0])){
            $where = $cats." AND ".$subCats." AND ".$colourCats;
        }
    //Search query.
    $search="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where ORDER BY $orderBy LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";  
    /*  
    Database Connection.
    */

    //Crate a database connection variable: $conn and error checking attributes.    
    $conn = new PDO($DB_SETTINGS, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    /*

    PDO WORK.

    */

    //SEARCH_LIKE_ALL QUERY!
    //Prepare query.
    $search_qry=$conn->prepare($search);
    //For each array index create array $rows.
    foreach ($values as $rows) {
        //Bind each value to $value_fields from $rows array.
        foreach ($rows as $key => &$value) {
            switch(gettype($value)) {
                case 'integer':
                case 'double':
                $search_qry->bindParam(':' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                break;
                default:
                $search_qry->bindParam(':' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }   
    }
    $search_qry->execute();
    $rows = $search_qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($rows);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

It builds the query fine. In my angularjs script I build a multidimensional array where index [0] contains data such as table, orderby and limits. Index [1] contains an array of Categories. Index[2] an array of Sub Categories and Index[3] an array of Colour Categories. My problem is that the search query is bring back data I am not expecting. So lets say I send this type of array:

```
values[0]={table: table, order_by: prod_code, limit: 10, offset 0}

values[1]={cat_id0: 1};

values[2]={sub_cat_id0: 1, sub_cat_id1: 3}

values[3]={colour_id0: 1, colour_id1: 2}
```

I want only products in cat 1 with sub cats 2 & 3 and a colour id 1 & 2. It is changing order when I remove a sub cat id from the array but is still in search, I assume this product is later being picked up by a colour id. Is the query wrong or the way in which I am searching.

From the array above:

```
$search="SELECT * FROM table WHERE cat_id=:cat_id0 AND sub_cat_id=:sub_cat_id0 OR sub_cat_id=:sub_cat_id1 AND colour_id=:colour_id0 OR colour_id=:colour_id1 ORDER BY prod_code LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0"
```

Comment: Unless you expect us to mentally construct your query from that wall of code, it would be a lot more helpful to post the complete query with the values you are using and a detailed description of what is wrong :-)

Comment: I agree with @jeroen and furthermore the example you're showing is open to sql injection. You should start using prepared statements.

Comment: By the way, the main problem (one of the...) is probably the way you combine `AND` and `OR` without parenthesis, causing the query to return a lot more than you expect.

Comment: Updated the code above.. @jeroen could you explain further please.

Comment: @jeroen Makes a great point. Example of what they are talking about: `$search="SELECT * FROM table WHERE (cat_id=:cat_id0 AND sub_cat_id=:sub_cat_id0) OR (sub_cat_id=:sub_cat_id0 AND (colour_id=:colour_id0 OR colour_id=:colour_id1)) ORDER BY prod_code LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0"`

Comment: so would this be correct: `WHERE (cat_id:cat_id0 AND  (sub_cat_id:=:sub_cat_id0 OR sub_cat_id:=:sub_cat_id1)) AND ((sub_cat_id:=:sub_cat_id0 OR sub_cat_id:=:sub_cat_id1) AND (colour_id=:colour_id0 OR colour_id=:colour_id1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the big problem you have is the order of precedence between `AND` and `OR`.

```
 SELECT a
      , b
      , c
      , a OR b AND c
      , (a OR b) AND c
   FROM ( SELECT 1 AS a UNION SELECT 0 ) a 
  CROSS
   JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS b UNION SELECT 0 ) b 
  CROSS
   JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS c UNION SELECT 0 ) c 
  WHERE NOT (a.a = b.b AND a.a = c.c)
  ORDER BY c, b, a 

     a       b       c  a OR b AND c  (a OR b) AND c  
------  ------  ------  ------------  --------------
     1       0       0             1               0
     0       1       0             0               0
     1       1       0             1               0
     0       0       1             0               0
     1       0       1             1               1
     0       1       1             1               1
```

That is to say

```
 foo = a OR foo = b AND bar = c
```

is evaluated as:

```
 ( foo = a ) OR ( foo = b AND bar = c )
```

when what you probably want is:

```
 (foo = a OR foo = b ) AND ( bar = c )
```

---

I'm having trouble deciphering what the  code is doing.

For example, why do you need all those permutations of conditions in building the `WHERE` clause? Why all those checks? Why not something simpler, like:

```
$where = " 1=1";
if (!empty($cats[0]) {
   $where .= " AND (" . $cats . ")";
} 
if (!empty($subCats[0]) {
   $where .= " AND (" . $subCats . ")";
} 
if (!empty($colourCats[0]) {
   $where .= " AND (" . $colourCats . ")";
}
```

Also, all those `OR` conditions testing equality

```
   foo = a OR foo = b OR foo = c OR foo = d
```

Can be expressed much more elegantly using an `IN`

```
   foo IN (a,b,c,d)
```

---

```
//Create cats fields
    $cats=array_keys($values[1]);
    if(empty($cats)) {
        $cats = null;
    } else {

        $cats=" cat_id IN (". implode(",",$cats) . ");

    }
```